# I2C RPi Python, and Atlas Scientific

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, i2c

So I am trying to get 2 Atlas Scientific sensors working. I decided to go with I2C as I need to have multiple sensors.

Following their DataSheet for I2C, and following an instructables page, I have run into some issues.

http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-I2C-Python/step5/Example-1-CMPS03-Compass-Module/

http://www.atlas-scientific.com/_files/_datasheets/_circuit/EC_EZO_Datasheet.pdf?

I am having issues getting it to recognize a command. The LED blinks red (cmd not understood) any time I try to do anything with it. They say they want the 'R' command passed to the device, wait 1 second, and read again to get the value, but I am having no luck

```
import smbus
import time
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
ph = 0x63
ec = 0x64
while True:
    try:
        print bus.read_byte_data(ec, 0x82)
        time.sleep(1)
    except IOError:
        pass
```

output

```
254
127
127
127
255
```

Comment: Hello! The linked datasheet is a conductivity sensor and the linked example is a compass. I assume they are operating differently however both supports I2C. Based on the datasheet the read data is not a byte but an array of bytes. Try to read with this: bus.read_i2c_block_data(0x64, 0x52, 48). This will send R to the device then read 48 bytes as an answer.
Ascii R is 82, hex is 0x52. You used 0x82 what is 130, and means a comma "," in ascii. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I know they are different. I am actively trying to do the EC and pH circuits from them.

Comment: I will give this a shot and post back soon

Comment: [127, 63, 159, 207, 231, 243, 249, 252, 254, 255, 127, 63, 159, 207, 231, 243, 249, 252, 254, 255, 127, 63, 159, 207, 231, 243, 249, 252, 254, 255, 127, 63, 159, 198, 182, 1, 82, 198, 182, 8, 0, 0, 0, 188, 51, 181, 190, 100]
[254, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 198, 182, 1, 82, 198, 182, 8, 0, 0, 0, 188, 51, 181, 190, 100]
[255, 127, 63, 159, 207, 231, 243, 249, 252, 254, 255, 127, 63, 159, 207, 231, 243, 249, 252, 254, 255, 127, 63, 159, 207, 231, 243, 249, 252, 254, 255, 127, 63, 198, 182, 1, 82, 198, 182, 8, 0, 0, 0, 188, ...

Comment: Sorry, there is a not in the datasheet that the response is never longer than 32 bytes so replace 48 with 32 in the buffer read command. Then I hope you will get the response in correct format and the first byte will be 255, 254, 2 or 1 as described in the manual.

Comment: And the response is text so you are receiving char values not floats or integers byte coded

Comment: So after changing to 32 bytes, I no longer receive '1' in any of my responses. I have also switch back and forth between the pH and EC sensors, and they are repeating the same pattern of responses. The responses from the 2 sensors should be totally different values. ph is 0.00-14.00 and EC is 0-100,000 or so.

Also, you are saying I will need to decode the byte value back into char correct?

Comment: [254, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]


    [127, 63, 159, 207, 231, 243, 249, 252, 254, 255, 255, 127, 63, 159, 207, 231, 243, 249, 252, 254, 255, 127, 63, 159, 207, 231, 243, 249, 252, 254, 255, 127]



Also, thank you very much for your help and patience. I do appreciate it.

Comment: I give up on using this markdown. UGH

Comment: To be honest the device datasheet is quite a mess for me and I have no experience with any Atlas sensors yet. But according to the manual the received bytes are chars as the i2c implementTion is a kind of hack of the uart protocol and the device is sending the serial data over the i2c interface. In the first answer the response is 254, this means the device is not yet ready. Maybe more waiting is neccessary? Try to wait 1 sec before reading, but it is guessing by me.

Comment: I have tried time.sleep(.3) and time.sleep(1). Maybe I should try 1.3?

Comment: Try to do a full power reset then wait for a couple seconds. I did not see any initialization in the manual but it might be neccessary before starting reading or at least all my sensors are working this way on the i2c interface

Comment: I think I have found my problem, although I cannot test because I accidentally put bunk byte value in and hung my pi. I will have to wait till I get home.

Watching the LEDs this morning, it never went blue, cyan, blue. It would go from blue to cyan, to red. Or blue to red. After reading the DataSheet again, I noticed they mentioned that after 1 second, the reading begins. When the LED returns to blue, then the reading is complete (I assume sitting in registry waiting for a read again). I think I am reading too often, and not giving the sensor time to take a reading before sending a request.

Comment: So I have now gotten the EZO circuit to blink from blue->cyan->blue, as if it has received a proper command. This is what I get from a time.sleep(5)

This is the pH probe, which is 7 bytes max (i pull 8)

[254, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[254, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[127, 63, 159, 207, 231, 243, 249, 252]
[254, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[254, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[254, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]